# How can I know whether specific string is included in strings? - C programming

Tags: find, character

I will input some strings and I want to know if Strings' first character is "1".
For example inputs would be,
1 2
2 3
1 5
5 2
5 6
4 7

But in this case , 2nd input 's first character is '2' not '1'
So I am so concerned that error would represent. How can I distinguish the strings of which first character is '1' from whose first character is not '1'?

```
#include<string.h>
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
char s1[10];
char s2[10];
char s3[10];
char s4[10];
char s5[10];
char s6[10];   
printf("Input strings ");
scanf("%s", s1);
scanf("%s", s2);
scanf("%s", s3);
scanf("%s", s4);
scanf("%s", s5);
scanf("%s", s6);

char* ptr1 = strchr(str, '1');    
char* ptr2 = strchr(str, '1');   
char* ptr3 = strchr(str, '1');
char* ptr4 = strchr(str, '1');
char* ptr5 = strchr(str, '1');
char* ptr6 = strchr(str, '1');
```

Answer (score 0):

Just check for s1[0] and use it in your code accordingly.

```
if(s1[0]=='1')
{
......your code
}
```

similarly for the rest of the strings.